# wx.ListCtrl: how can I select a row on EVT_RIGHT_DOWN?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm writing a simple database GUI with wxpython.

In order to display my database entries, I'm using a [`wx.ListCtrl`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ListCtrl-class.html). Let's consider the following code snippet:

```
class BookList(wx.ListCtrl):
  def __init__(self, parent, ID=wx.ID_ANY):
    wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, ID)

    self.InsertColumn(0, 'Title')
    self.InsertColumn(1, 'Author')

    # set column width ...

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN, self.OnRightDown)


  def OnRightDown(self, event):
    menu = wx.Menu()
    delete = menu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, 'Delete Item')

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnDelete, delete)

    # select row

    self.PopupMenu(menu, event.GetPosition())
```

I can't figure out how to select the row before spawning the menu.

I thought about two possible solutions:

1. Use [`wx.ListCtrl.Select()`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ListCtrl-class.html#Select), but I don't know how to obtain `idx` parameter corresponding to the row I want to select.
2. Trigger `wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN`, but I don't know how (and even if) it could be done.

Am I on the right way? Is there any better solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that involves both the possible solutions I guessed.

I have keep track of the currently selected row. The snippet speaks itself:

```
class BookList(wx.ListCtrl):
  def __init__(self, parent, ID=wx.ID_ANY):
    wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, ID)

    self.InsertColumn(0, 'Title')
    self.InsertColumn(1, 'Author')

    # set column width ...

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnLeftDown)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN, self.OnRightDown)

    # currently selected row
    self.cur = None


  def OnLeftDown(self, event):
    if self.cur != None:
      self.Select( self.cur, 0) # deselect currently selected item

    x,y = event.GetPosition()
    row,flags = self.HitTest( (x,y) )

    self.Select(row)
    self.cur = row


  def OnRightDown(self, event):
    menu = wx.Menu()
    delete = menu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, 'Delete Item')

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnDelete, delete)

    # select row
    self.OnLeftDown(event)

    self.PopupMenu(menu, event.GetPosition())
```